# How to PHP Server Side Render (SSR) a URL that is 100% javascript generated then save it to a static html file

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to monitor a URL using online monitoring services, but these services do not render javascript. My only option is to use my own server and server side render these URL's via PHP and then output it back to my own domain for monitoring. What PHP tools lets me do a SSR that outputs it to a static html? Or if there is an easier method without PHP, that would be nice too.

Comment: I think this kind of question is opinion based and maybe it'll be closed. Anyway, asking google I've found this as the first result: https://github.com/spatie/server-side-rendering Hope it helps you.

Comment: sounds like you are talking about a headless browser, do you have the code the JS app? is it built with one of the famous frameworks? usually frameworks like react and angular have their own implement for SSR.

Comment: I'm trying to just monitor a page like this: https://www.lokisn.com/sn/32d206645743b6c389ecdb24f143b0c548896e38534c45c2dc33328af46a4607